# replaceAll( ) not working in replacing lines in a CSV txt file

Tags: java, replaceall

I'm trying to replace a certain line in a text file using the `replaceAll()` method but every time i try to run it, it doesn't change at all. I even tried to covert the string `oldUser` to a regex (`Pattern.quote(oldUser)`), am I missing something?

Text File Contents (person.txt):

```
ABCDEFG1,THERONE ALMADIN,theronealmadin@gmail.com,DAVAO CITY,06/09/1999,09226217885,8000
GFEDCBA2,NATHAN ANG,nathanang@gmail.com,BUTUAN CITY,01/02/2000,09451236987,8000
ADEACAS3,ANTON MARITIREZ,antonmaritirez@gmail.com,GENSAN CITY,02/13/2001,09214561236,8000
AABBCCDD,NAME HERE,emailhere@gmail.com,CITY HERE CITY,12/31/2000,11112223333,8000
```

My code in particular:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String oldUser = "AABBCCDD,NEW NAME,emailhere@gmail.com,CITY HERE CITY,12/31/2000,11112223333,8000";

        String newUser = "AABBCCDD,NAME HERE,emailhere@gmail.com,CITY HERE CITY,12/31/2000,11112223333,8000";

        String filepath = "person.txt";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (new File(filepath));

        StringBuilder bufferedList = new StringBuilder();

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            bufferedList.append(scanner.nextLine()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }

        String personContents = bufferedList.toString();
        System.out.println("old data: " + personContents);
        scanner.close();

        System.out.println("REGEX" + Pattern.quote(oldUser));
        personContents = personContents.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(oldUser), newUser);

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filepath);

        System.out.println("new data: " + personContents);
        writer.append(personContents);
        writer.flush();

    }
}
```

Comment: You have oldUser and newUser back to front in your code.

Comment: Either the data isn't getting replaced, in which case the file-writing is not relevant, or the file-writing isn't working, in which case the regex replacement is not relevant. You should be able to determine which by debugging your code, and this will help you to narrow down your issue to one specific problem; please see [mcve].

Comment: @kaya3 there! i just excerpted it form a larger project and I think it should run as intended.

Comment: As tgdavies writes in his comment: you are trying to replace `"AABBCCDD,NEW NAME,emailhere@gmail.com,CITY HERE CITY,12/31/2000,11112223333,8000"` with `"AABBCCDD,NAME HERE,emailhere@gmail.com,CITY HERE CITY,12/31/2000,11112223333,8000"`, but  `"AABBCCDD,NEW NAME,emailhere@gmail.com,CITY HERE CITY,12/31/2000,11112223333,8000"` cannot be found in your input and is therefore not replaced.

Comment: @ThomasKläger oh wait does that mean i have the two parameters switched? I have it attached to a class where it actually finds the user and it returns to me a match, meaning it has found the old user.

Comment: okay im dumb so i did switch the two lol. Thanks alot for @ThomasKläger and tgdavies

Answer (score 0):

Okay so im gonna answer my own question here.

I had the parameters for replaceAll() switched.